# Múltiplos de 2 números em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa em C que pede o valor de n e dois números inteiros positivos i e j. Com esses valores eu tenho que calcular os n números naturais que são são múltiplos de i ou de j e ou de ambos. Mas o meu código por algum motivo o programa trava depois da leitura dos valores, não calcula nenhum múltiplo e encerra.

```
int n, i, j, contador, multiplosI, multiplosJ;

printf("Digite o valor de N : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Digite o valor de I e J : ");
scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);

multiplosI = 0;
multiplosJ = 0;

for (int contador = 0; contador < n; contador ++){
    if (i % contador == 0 && j % contador == 0){
        multiplosI = contador;
        printf("Multiplos de I e J : %d \n",multiplosI);
    } else if (i % contador == 0){
        multiplosI = contador;
        printf("Multiplos apenas de I : %d \n",multiplosI);
    } else {
        multiplosJ = contador;
        printf("Multiplos apenas de J : %d \n",multiplosJ);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do problema você quer calcular os **n** múltiplos e não limitar cada um dos múltiplos a *n*.

Uma ideia é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, i, j, k=0, cont=0, mult_i=0, mult_j=0, mult_ij=0;
    printf("Digite o valor de N : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Digite o valor de I e J : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    while (cont <= n) {
        k++;
        if ((k%i == 0) && (k%j == 0)) {
            mult_ij++;
            cont++;
        }
        else {
            if (k%i == 0) {
                mult_i++;
                cont++;
            }
            else {
                if (k%j == 0) {
                    mult_j++;
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("Multiplos de %d e %d : %d \n", i, j, mult_ij);
    printf("Multiplos apenas de %d : %d \n", i, mult_i);
    printf("Multiplos apenas de %d : %d \n", j, mult_j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Só não conseguir entender o porque tem 2 contadores no programa.

Answer (score 2):

Tem vários problemas no código e espero ter entendido o problema. Algumas coisas eu mudei porque fica melhor apenas.

Não tenho certeza mas duvido que deva começar avaliar do 0 então comecei do 1.

A contagem só deve ser apresentada no final do laço quando terminou de fazê-la e não no meio da contagem.

Faltou contar quando é múltiplo de ambos, misturou com a contagem de I. E eu simplifiquei (provavelmente tornei mais performático) para achar ambos).

Considerei que deve ser exclusivamente ambos, ser for inclusivamente aí não deveria calcular assim e o resultado correto seria só a soma dos dois outros acumuladores, mas duvido que seja isso.

Não estava incrementando o contador dos múltiplos, estava pegando o valor atual do contador, que não faz o menor sentido. A contagem é condicional, então cada uma deve ser independentemente incrementada.

Também fazia a conta do resto ao contrário, o correto é pegar o resto da divisão do contador pelo divisor estabelecido, estava usando o contador como divisor, também não faz sentido.

Preferi não mexer nos nomes das variáveis, mas normalmente eu usaria outros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, i, j, multiplosI = 0, multiplosJ = 0, multiplos = 0;
    printf("Digite o valor de N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Digite o valor de I e J: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    for (int contador = 1; contador < n; contador++) {
        if (contador % i == 0) multiplosI++;
        if (contador % j == 0) multiplosJ++;
        if (contador % (i * j) == 0) multiplos++;
    }
    printf("\nMultiplos apenas de I: %d", multiplosI);
    printf("\nMultiplos apenas de J: %d", multiplosJ);
    printf("\nMultiplos de ambos: %d", multiplos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BeWBJ0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Multiplesc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futur](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Multiples.c)a.